# Error when try to install BEEGO

Tags: go, beego

I am very new with GO, and when I tried to install the framwork beego on my Windows 8 Desktop or in a VirtualBox with Debian8 I had the same error:

```
sergi@odoo:~$ go get github.com/astaxie/beego
# github.com/astaxie/beego
work/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/tree.go:144: syntax error: unexpected range, expecting {
work/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/tree.go:155: syntax error: unexpected else, expecting semicolon or newline
work/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/tree.go:157: non-declaration statement outside function body
work/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/tree.go:158: non-declaration statement outside function body
work/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/tree.go:159: non-declaration statement outside function body
work/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/tree.go:160: syntax error: unexpected }
work/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/tree.go:257: syntax error: unexpected range, expecting {
work/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/tree.go:267: syntax error: unexpected else, expecting semicolon or newline or }
work/src/github.com/astaxie/beego/tree.go:283: syntax error: unexpected }
```

Comment: What version of Go are you using? You may be using an old version of Go which is probably having issues building the beego package. I tried on OSX with go 1.5.3 and it worked fine.

Comment: Yeah, probably the go version. Just checked with 1.5.3 on windows 8 and it runs with no problems.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be using an old Go version which is failing to build the `beego` package.

Note that the package is only tested against `go 1.5.1`. So try upgrading to go `1.5.x` and attempt to fetch it again.

https://github.com/astaxie/beego/blob/master/.travis.yml#L4

I'm pretty sure the upgrade will fix your issues.

Answer (score 1):

The empty `for range` loops were introduced in [Go 1.4](https://golang.org/doc/go1.4#forrange). Your Go version seems to be older. Check your version with

```
go version
```

and if it's older than 1.4, install a newer version [from the official website](https://golang.org/dl/).